# List supported authorites for selected accounts

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contentresolver, accounts

I'm trying to develop an application which syncs only selected accounts using `ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, extras);`.

I was able to **sync** contacts and calendar by using `com.android.contacts` and `com.android.calendar` respectively as `authority`.

But, is there any way to get the **list of authorities** supported by a specific account?

Also, what is the effect of using `null` as `authority`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getSyncAdapterTypes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAdapterTypes%28%29) to get information about the `SyncAdapters` that are known to the system.

```
SyncAdapterType[] types = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType type : types) {
    if (yourAccount.type.equals(type.accountType)) {
        boolean isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(yourAccount, type.authority) > 0;
        if (isSyncable) {
            ContentResolver.requestSync(yourAccount, type.authority, extras);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget [getIsSyncable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getIsSyncable%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) method requires [READ_SYNC_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SYNC_SETTINGS) permission.

Comment: Thankz @biegleux.. its working.. but, its not giving the authority to sync emails.. any idea??